# forEach assíncrono em javascript

Tags: javascript, assincronismo

Bom dia!

Depois de quebrar muita a cabeça e não achar a solução, vim perguntar aos amigos do SOpt. É possível criar um forEach assíncrono?

Porque o seguinte, olhem meu código:

```
async function generateWishlist() {
    var products = [];
    var productLength = 0;

    JSON.parse(getCookieVal('whishlistLEL')).forEach(function(e) {
         fetch("/api/catalog_system/pub/products/search?fq=productId:" + e)
        .then(a => a.json())
        .then(a => {
            products.push(a[0]);
            console.log("Estou passando por aqui hahah, estou te trolando, Lucas")
            productLength++;
        });      
    });  
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        resolve([products, productLength]);
    });
}

async function initWishlist() {
    if(!verifyWishlist()) {
        console.log("Você não possui produtos na lista de desejos!");
        return false;
    }
    await generateWishlist()
    .then(function(resolve) {
        console.log(resolve);
    })
}

initWishlist();
```

Desconsiderem as funções `verifyWishlist()` e `getCookieVal()` elas estão sendo usadas mas não fazem parte do problema. (só pra deixar o exemplo do código menor)

O que eu tenho de retorno é isso aqui na imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O array veio ok, o indice 0 trouxe normalmente, já o indice 1, não fez a contagem que coloquei ali, creio eu por conta do foreach não ser assíncrono...

Teria como eu criar esse forEach de modo assíncrono?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não sei se você entende direito o conceito de async e await. Se você declarar uma função como async, todo o retorno será empacotado em uma promise, você não precisa retornar uma promise dentro de uma função async.

Para resolver todas as suas promises de forma que você não tenha que esperar pela resolução da anterior, basta usar o método nativo Promise.all, passando um array de promises.

```
async function generateWishlist() {
    const obj = JSON.parse(getCookieVal('whishlistLEL'));

    const fetchPromises = obj.map(f => fetch(`/api/catalog_system/pub/products/search?fq=productId:${f}`));
    const stream = await Promise.all(fetchPromises);
    const streamPromises = stream.map(s => s.json());
    const products = await Promise.all(streamPromises);

    return [products, products.length];
}
```

Mas lembre-se de que sem tratamento, se uma das promises lançar uma exceção, você irá perder a resolução das demais.

Answer (score 1):

o que faltou foi o `await` na frete do `fetch`

exemplo:

```js
async function generateWishlist() {
    var products = [];
    var productLength = 0;
    var lista = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
   for (i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {
   await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/" + lista[i])
        .then(a => a.json())
        .then(a => {
            products.push(a[0]);
            console.log("Estou passando por aqui hahah, estou te trolando, Lucas")
            productLength++;
        });   
   }
}


generateWishlist();
```